# Updating OpenStreetMap in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I can't use `imposm` tool, because it is not compatible with Nominatim. 
So it seems that I can use only `osm2pgsql`. But is there any ready to use toolchain, that allows to update OSM in an easy way.

I looked at docs and it seems that I need to do all by hands.

Is there any tested version that are ready to work?

Comment: Have you looked at osmosis?  I don't know if it is nominatim compatible, but you can do differential updates.

Comment: Not sure which documentation you looked at. The wiki has a chapter on running updates: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Updating_Nominatim